# How to set date to datetime format or timestamp in calendar Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I use the following [Angular JS calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar).

When I select date I get date format:

```
calendarDay: Sat Oct 10 2015 20:07:14 GMT+0500 (Грузинское время (лето))
```

How I can save this date in format timestamp or datetime for MySql in hidden input field?

Comment: can you show some sample how are you using this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `getTime` method of the date:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{calendarDay.getTime()}}">
```

Tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Do you mean `calendarDay.getTime()`?

Comment: Well, if the time is wrong is because the date is wrong. What exactly is wrong in the timestamp?